# Dynamic variable names in MySQL

Tags: mysql, function, variables

I need to create some stored function in MySQL that will work exactly like getter/setter and return or set for me variable by it's name.

For example `get_variable('my_special')` will return me value of `@my_special variable`, `set_variable('my_special', 23)` will set `@my_special := 23`.

Question is: how can I, having variable name as a string set or get it in MySQL?
Smth `like SET @{'my_special'} = 23` or `$$var = 23` (as in PHP)

**Update:** According to my task I found that it's impossible to do in mysql. The purpose I wanted this was a chain of events:

- I wanted to store query with variables as a view in DB. MySQL rejects storing view with variables but allows with using functions.
- I've decided I'll create functions which will return/set my variables. But I had about 4 variables inside query - so it's not efficient to create 4 pairs of functions to get/set variables. So I've wanted to create universal getters/setters.
- Only way to get/set variable by name is to run dynamic query which are forbidden inside functions(only in procedures which are not very comfortable to use inside select statements).
- So as a result of this question - it's impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create procedure `eval`( in param text )                                                                                                                   
begin 
    set @sql = param; 
    prepare stmt from @sql; 
    execute stmt; 
    deallocate prepare stmt; 
end
```

Call the procedure `call tests.eval('set @ABC = 120')` and in the current session, you can access the variable @ABC

```
call tests.eval('set @ABC = 120');
select @ABC;
```

[Source](https://gist.github.com/pixe1f10w/3863897)

Answer (score 0):

If you must do this in SQL you're going to need the MySQL feature called *[Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).*  Despite its name, this is not the same as the client-side *prepare()* feature offered by JDBC, mysqli, PDO, and other apis supporting client side languages.

Why? SQL doesn't allow the names of database objects (tables, columns, &c.) to be handled as bind variables.

Comment: Prepared statements forbidden in functions

Comment: Oh, true enough. If you must do this, you need a stored PROCEDURE. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48262/dynamic-sql-is-not-allowed-error-for-creating-function-in-mysql