# Lack of dynamic variable names in MySQL, isn't there a risk of a collision using session variables in stored procedures?

Tags: mysql, scope

To the best of my knowledge:
When using prepared statements inside a stored procedure, I need to use a session-variable:

```
SET temp_table = CONCAT("temp_table_",replace(uuid(), '-', ''));  
SET @sql = CONCAT('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ',temp_table);
PREPARE query from @sql;
EXECUTE query;
SET @sql = NULL;
```

According to this earlier question: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33670284/dynamic-variable-names-in-mysql)

It is not possible to dynamically create session variable names.(i.e generate a randomly named session variable)

Question:
If I start to have dozens of stored procedures, and I lazily always use @sql, and I have hundreds of user actions per second...   does this not create a collision risk?

This seems like bad practice, what am I missing / what do you do to eliminate this risk?

Comment: Scope of `@sql` is only for a particular **SESSION**. So there may be 1000s of users, but all of them will have **different sessions**, and thus each one of them have their own `sql` variable to play with.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  Since my php pages all use the same mysql login, this didn't occur to me.

Comment: Actually, if the variable was created within a `stored procedure`, then the scope of each `@sql` is only for the particular `stored procedure` in which it was created.